# Single-source path of given weight in undirected graph

Tags: graph-theory, weighted-graph

I’m trying to find an algorithm that from a given vertex u and a given weight w finds a circular path of weight w starting and ending at vertex u.

My first idea was to apply Floyd-Warshall algorithm then make a random walk from vertex u until I find a vertex v from which the sum of the weight of the random walk and the weight of the shortest path between u and v equals w.

The problem is : I’m not sure to find a path with this algorithm.

Do you have any other ideas ?

Comment: My first idea would be to try a dynamic programming algorithm: fill an array with one column per vertex v and one row per weight 0 <= k <= w. The cell on row k, column v represents a path from v to u of weight k, if such a path exists. Then find a recursive formula to fill a given cell of this array, given that previous cells have already been filled; The solution of your problem will be in row w, column u.

Comment: Thanks a lot I'm gonna try this :)